# Swift. I pull out pictures in cells through api. Everything is being built, but instead of pictures it's empty. Returns nil. Explain please

Tags: ios, swift, image

I'm a beginner. I pull out pictures in cells through api. Everything is built, but instead of pictures - it's empty. Returns nil. I've been sitting here all day and can't figure it out!

API link - https://swiftbook.ru//wp-content/uploads/api/api_courses

If this answer is somewhere, I apologize, and if it's not difficult to give a link, send it please, thank you.

Thank you very much in advance for your help and clarification!!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0hQW.png)

```
import UIKit

class CourseCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var courseImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var courseNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var numberOfLessons: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var numberOfTests: UILabel!
    
    func configure(with course: Course) {
        
        courseNameLabel.text = course.name
        numberOfLessons.text = "Number of lessons \(course.number_of_lessons ?? 0)"
        numberOfTests.text = "Number of tests \(course.number_of_tests ?? 0)"
        
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            
            guard let stringUrl = course.imageUrl,
                  let imageURL = URL(string: stringUrl),
                  let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
            else {
                return
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.courseImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            }      
   
        }   
    }
}
```

**Model for decode by JSON**

```
Course.swift

struct Course: Decodable {
    let name: String?
    let imageUrl: String?
    let number_of_lessons: Int?
    let number_of_tests: Int?
}

struct WebsiteDescription: Decodable {
    let courses: [Course]?
    let websiteDescription: String?
    let websiteName: String?
}
```

**And piece of code with JSON from CoursesViewController.swift**

```
extension CoursesViewController {
    func fetchCourses() {
        guard let url = URL(string: URLExamples.exampleTwo.rawValue) else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            
            do {
                // получаем курсы в переменную
                self.courses = try JSONDecoder().decode([Course].self, from: data)
                // и мы должны перезагрузить таблицу
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

**And here is i get nil probably (please see screenshot below)**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm1qW.jpg)

Comment: is the imageURL pointing to a local image file or some image from the web?

Comment: If you are reading a book / tutorial that says it's okay to say `Data(contentsOf: imageURL)` for a remote (`https`) URL, then you need to throw that book / tutorial away.

Comment: As for why the image is not appearing: well, first of all, the code is wrong (cells are reused, so it makes no sense to download and show directly in a cell — the correct procedure is to update the _data model_), but also, hey, if something is `nil`, find out what it is and why. Debug and see what your code is actually doing.

Comment: Dear @WitekBobrowski, imageUrl (not imageUrl) - is one of the properties of the struct in the Model-file I created, for decoding the URL API via JSON

I will add the code in the question now

Comment: `guard let stringUrl = course.imageUrl, ... else { return }`: Is this return called? But as said, get rid of `Data(contentsOf:)` in 99% of your cases if that's a remote URL...

Comment: Hey @matt, big tanks for your comment, I appreciate it, please see addition to the my question. I already do it yeah, and here is the place (let imageData) where i get nil !(

Comment: Dear @Larme thanks for your time! Ok, but can can you please explain why (shortly maybe), and what will be better nowadays ?

Comment: `Data(contentsOf:)` blocks the current thread. If you are in main thread, it means freezing the application. It's better to use `URLSession` that will do it on its own thread. Of courser, you can use as you wrote a `DispatchQueue.async`, but that's extra work. Also, `Data(contentsOf:)` can only do a simple get (no parameters, no headers/tokens, etc.). So keep using URLSession as a good practice. Also, you are using `try?` Never ignore possible errors, always use `try` (without question mark) in a `do`/`catch`, unless you can debug yourself (and even, it's better to use `do`/`catch`).

Comment: Finally, there are third party library that do nicely loading of images (and with the `UITableView` & reuse mechanism, it's quite nice), like SDWebImage, KingFisher, Alamofire+Image, etc.

Comment: @Larme I'm grateful a lot for your time and answers, I saved it in the notes. I'll try to do it

Comment: Dear colleagues, do you want to know the real reason for this problem? It's a brain explosion. WHEN I ACCIDENTALLY TURNED ON THE VPN ON THE MAC AND BUILD APP, THEN EVERYTHING LOADED!!! All because I am in Ukraine now, and we have all .ru domains blocked, and the API URL is just on .ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to make another version of your code and it's able to run. You can check my code and compare with your own.

**CoursesViewController**

```
class CoursesViewController: UIViewController {
    private lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        tableView.register(CourseCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CourseCell")

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        return tableView
    }()

    private var courses: [Course] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupViews()
        setupLayout()

        fetchCourses()
    }

    private func setupViews() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    private func setupLayout() {
        tableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }

    private func fetchCourses() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://swiftbook.ru//wp-content/uploads/api/api_courses") else {
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }

            do {
                // получаем курсы в переменную
                self.courses = try JSONDecoder().decode([Course].self, from: data)
                // и мы должны перезагрузить таблицу
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

extension CoursesViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        courses.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CourseCell", for: indexPath) as? CourseCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

        cell.configure(with: courses[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        120
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        120
    }
}
```

**Cell**

```
class CourseCell: UITableViewCell {
    private lazy var nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()

        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textColor = .black
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .bold)

        return label
    }()

    private lazy var courseImage = UIImageView(frame: .zero)

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        setupViews()
        setupLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func configure(with course: Course) {
        nameLabel.text = course.name

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            guard let stringUrl = course.imageUrl,
                  let imageURL = URL(string: stringUrl),
                  let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
            else {
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Make sure it's the same course
                self.courseImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            }
        }
    }

    private func setupViews() {
        courseImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(courseImage)
    }

    private func setupLayout() {
        nameLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(8)
        }

        courseImage.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.centerX.equalToSuperview().inset(8)
            make.top.equalTo(nameLabel.snp.bottom).offset(12)
            make.height.width.equalTo(80)
        }
    }
}
```

- In my opinion, you should check your UI layout to make sure that the image view can be loaded and displayed properly.

**Some Improvement suggestion**

- `Course.swift`: Please use lower camel case convention for variables name because it's the common Swift convention
- `CourseCell.swift`: Since the course don't have ID so after a while you load image from background, this cell might be used by another because of the reuse cell mechanism.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // Make sure it's the same course
    if course.id == self.course.id {
        self.courseImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
}
```

- Use caching mechanism every time you load image from the server so that next time you don't need to fetch from the server again (you can set timeout for cache)
- Instead of handing loading image by yourself, you can use well-known 3rd party libs like `SDWebImage` or `KingFisher`.

Comment: Oh, great BIG Thanks for that, I will compare now !!! And I'm very grateful for correction instructions!!! I will learn it

Comment: And about camelCase, yes i knew it, but i use this only for work with API Parameters, to make there names exactly the same. Correct me if I wrong

Comment: You can define CodingKey. Here is the tutorial from Apple https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: And by the way, do you want to know the real reason for this problem? It's a brain explosion. WHEN I ACCIDENTALLY TURNED ON THE VPN ON THE MAC AND BUILD APP, THEN EVERYTHING LOADED!!! All because I am in Ukraine now, and we have all .ru domains blocked, and the API URL is just on .ru

Comment: Yah, I see. Sometimes it's take hours to debug trivial problems :D.

Comment: Hah, mind blowing

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is Excellent !!! It's an additional valuable experience for me!

But main reason was in blocked .ru domains in my country. WHEN I ACCIDENTALLY TURNED ON THE VPN ON THE MAC AND BUILD APP, THEN EVERYTHING LOADED!!! Because I am in Ukraine now, and we have all .ru domains blocked, and the API URL is just on .ru